# Given these three vectors, find the intersection of the three planes:

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the three vectors, find the intersection of the three planes:

$n_1 = (1,2,3)$
$n_2 = (3,2,1)$
$n_3 = (1,-2,-5)$

What happens if $n_3 = (1,-2,-4)$? Why is this different?

Comment: Where do the said planes come from?

Comment: @Javier Putting these three vectors in a matrix and reducing the matrix. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to find the points of intersection, however.

Comment: @user125084 ni*x=0 is the only other information given in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going in the right direction putting them in a matrix and row-reducing. Doing that with the original 3 vectors does not give you the identity matrix, which implies that the three given vectors are linearly dependent. So you will see that the three planes will intersect in a line.

However, when $n_3$ is changed to $(1,-2,-4)$, the matrix does row-reduce to the identity matrix, implying linear independence of the three vectors. Then, the three planes would intersect only at a point, the origin.

Edit: actually, I should be more explicit in my explanation, especially the first part.

Suppose a point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ lies on the planes $x+2y+3z=0$, $3x+2y+x=0$, and $x-2y-5z=0$. From this system of linear equations, we get the augmented matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & -5 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
which row-reduces to
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Hence, we have that $x_1 = x_3$ and $x_2 = -2x_3$. Thus, if point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ were to lie in the intersection of the three planes, $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_3, -2x_3, x_3) = x_3 (1,-2,1)$. Thus, the intersection of the three planes is a line with the vector equation $L(t) = (0,0,0) + t\langle 1,-2,1 \rangle$.